# Is there a meaningful difference between two ways of writing a Manipulate expression?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, function-comparison

What is the difference between

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Disk[{x, 0}, 1], Axes -> True], {x, 0, 10}]
```

and

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Translate[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], {x, 0}], Axes -> True], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Both appear to give the same visualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `x` is an abscissa of the Disk there is no point in using `Translate` which only makes the code longer.

If you want to scale the code and really translate a lot of graphics primitives then `Translate` makes sense as it can do it in bulk.

Eventually the best improvement here would be to wrap `x` with `Dynamic`. That way FrontEnd can take care of updating the position of the disc instead of recreating the whole `Graphics` scene. See more in tutorial/AdvencedDynamicFunctionality in Nesting Dynamics functionality.

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[
    Translate[{Circle[], Rectangle[]}, {Dynamic@x, 0}], 
    Axes -> True, 
    PlotRange -> 12
  ], 
  {x, 0, 10}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that they a nearly equivalent. The only difference I see is that

```
Translate[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], {x, 0}]
```

might be slightly slower than

```
Disk[{x, 0}, 1]
```

if this is used very often in a single `Manipulate`.